# How does the Count property work in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I've made a most unfortunate typo costing me quite some precious time:

```
$errors.Count
```

This returns "`0`", even if there are errors, because the variable name should be *singular*. This *does* work:

```
$error.clear()                # To ensure a correct repro
Copy-Item asdf fdsa           # Will show an error
$error.Count                  # Will output "1"
```

However, I now want to know why `$errors.Count` gave me *anything at all*, and why it gave me "`0`". So I went on to do some testing, and got the following results:

```
$asdf.Count                   # Will output "0"
$nrOfEinsteinsInSpace.Count   # Will output "0"
$a = 0; $a.Count;             # Will output "1"
$b = 2; $a.Count;             # Will output "1"
$x = 1,2,3; $x.Count;         # Will output "3"
```

And gathering even more data to be able to ask a sensible question here I did:

```
$true.Count                   # Will output "1"
$false.Count                  # Will output "1"
```

So we have the following different cases:

1. Array(like) variables, where `.Count` will output the number of items.
2. Non-existent variables, where `.Count` will output "0".
3. Declared variables, where `.Count` will output "1".
4. Built-in variables, where `.Count` will output "1".

Case 2, 3, and 4 don't make any sense to me (yet). What is going on here? Where is this documented? How does the `.Count` property work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Starting in PowerShell V3, the properties Count and Length received very special treatment not related to extended type data (also known as ETS or extended type system).

If the instance has a Count/Length property, then everything continues to work like it did in V1/V2 - the value from the instance is returned.

If the instance does not have a Count/Length property, starting in V3, instead of that being an error, you'll get back 1.  And if the instance is $null, you'll get back 0.  If you have turned on strict mode, you'll get an error like in V2.

I'll admit this is a bit strange, but it solves a common problem when a cmdlet returns 0, 1, or multiple objects.

Often, you'll iterate through those results via the pipeline or with a foreach statement.  For example:

```
dir nosuchfile* | % { $_ }
foreach ($item in dir nosuchfile*) { $_ }
```

In the foreach case above, V2 would actually enter the loop if the command didn't return any values.  That was changed in V3 to better match peoples expectations, but that also meant that:

```
foreach ($item in $null) { $_ }
```

also never enters the loop.

The for statement is another way to iterate through results, e.g.

```
$results = dir nosuchfile*
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $results.Count; $i++) { $results[$i] }
```

In this example, it doesn't matter how many objects are in $result, the loop works just fine.  Note that in V1/V2, you would have written:

```
$results = @(dir nosuchfile*)
```

This ensures $results is an array, but this syntax is ugly and many folks would forget it, hence the change to support Count/Length in a slightly more forgiving way.

Comment: Wow, a rather different answer than the other two by @DavidBrabant and Paul. I appreciate both efforts, I'm not sure if I'm properly qualified to decide which answer to accept. Will have to check at work tomorrow if I see similar difference between V2 and V3. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I'm the developer on the PowerShell team that implemented this, so ignoring faulty memories, my answer is about as authoritative as you can get.

Comment: Beware that **strict** mode still throws an error as Jason notes! That one had me scratching my head...

Comment: When iterating over items returned by a function is this complicated, it sure dampens enthusiasm for the capabilities powershell enables.

Answer (score 6):

To complement Paul's answer, this might be related to [extended type data](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847881.aspx). To quote the relevant part of the documentation:

> Extended type data defines additional properties and methods
>   ("members") of object types in Windows PowerShell. You can extend any
>   type that is  supported by Windows PowerShell and use the added
>   properties and methods in the same way that you use the properties
>   that are defined on the object types.

And:

> There are three sources of extended type data in Windows PowerShell
>   sessions.
>   The Types.ps1xml files in the Windows PowerShell installation directory are loaded automatically into every Windows PowerShell session.

If you open that Types.ps1xml file (in `$pshome`), you'll see this at the beginning of the file:

```xml
   <Type>
        <Name>System.Array</Name>
        <Members>
            <AliasProperty>
                <Name>Count</Name>
                <ReferencedMemberName>Length</ReferencedMemberName>
            </AliasProperty>
        </Members>
    </Type>
```

So my guess is that by providing the "`.Count`" property, PowerShell assumes this is an array.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how i think it works:

Case 1: In Arrays the `.Count` Property actually links to the `.Length` property which shows the number of Items in the Array

Case 2: Non-exitent variables get automatically created by powershell and initialized with value `$null`

Case 3 / 4: On this one i am not exactly sure why it happens but since neither String nor Int or boolean Objects have a `.Count` property i could imagine that the Property is inherited by a parent-object.

The behaviour suggests that the variable is treated as array so with 1 Value assigned the output will be 1, without a value the result will be 0.

Edit:
For the sake of completeness here is the Link to the Documentation: [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847881.aspx), thanks @David Brabant