# Formatting output from PowerShell to a csv file

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Trying to output two variable results from Active Directory to PowerShell and format on one line of a .csv file with each returned variable in separate cells. The input file contains the names of four AD groups. The task is to count the users in each group and return the total number of users.

The goal is to write to the .csv file formatting the output with the ad group name in one cell and the user count in the next cell to the right.

This is a simple script built by starting with reading the file and returning the results to the screen. Attempted to write to the file using Export-Csv with no success. The Add-Content has been the most successful technique.

The following code works part of the way, but the ad group name and the user count is written to the same cell in the .csv file. Earlier attempts wrote the AD group name on a line and the total # of users on the next line.

```
foreach($object in $groupfile){
    $groupName = $object.adgroupname
    $groupName = $groupName.Trim()
    $users = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupName
    $usercount = $users.Count
    $groupinfo = ($groupName + " " + $usercount)

    # both of the lines below return the information to the screen on on line
    Write-Host $groupname, $usercount
    Write-Host $groupinfo

    # this line returns the information as shown below in the First result
    Add-Content -Path $filepath $groupname, $usercount

    # this line writes to the file as shown below in the Second result
    Add-Content -Path $filepath $groupinfo
}
```

First result (acceptable for a small number of groups, but a more robust solution is necessary for a larger number of groups.): 
ad group name one
357
ad group name two
223
ad group name three
155
ad group name four
71

Second result (both values for the returned variable are in one cell): 
ad group name one 357
ad group name two 223
ad group name three 155
ad group name four 71

The goal is to write to the .csv file formatting the output with the ad group name in one cell and the user count in the next cell to the right.

Comment: I made an obvious mistake in the following line; # both of the lines below return the information to the screen on one line

Comment: the usual way to do this is to build a custom object that has the desired props from the various sources in ONE object [a CSV row]. then use `Export-CSV` to build a proper CSV file automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your variable `$groupfile` is the result of a `Import-Csv` command.

If I understand the question properly, you could do this:

```
# loop through the $groupfile rows and collect the results as objects
$result = $groupfile | ForEach-Object {
    $groupName = $_.adgroupname.Trim()
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'GroupName' = $groupName
        'UserCount' = @(Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupName).Count
    }
}

# display on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# export to csv
$result | Export-Csv -Path $filepath -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Should output a csv, something like

> ```
> "GroupName","UserCount"
> "ad group name one","357"
> "ad group name two","223"
> "ad group name three","155"
> "ad group name four","71"
> ```

<sup>Note: the `Get-ADGroupMember` can return objects of type `user`, `group` and `computer`, so either name the second column `ObjectCount` of add a `Where-Object {$_.objectClass -eq 'user'}` clause to the `Get-ADGroupMember` function to filter only user objects</sup>

Hope that helps

Comment: What does using an AT SIGN in `= @(Get-ADGroupMember ...` accomplish? Using `@()` indicates an array.

Comment: @lit Yes, that is so we can be sure we get an array (even if empty) in order to be able to use `.Count`

Comment: Using `.Count` works on base (non-array) types; always returning one (1). If an array were needed, I would have thought that `@(, (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupName)).Count` would be needed. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @lit. That is only true for PowerShell 3.0 and up (unless you have turned on strict mode). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26513523/9898643) explains it a lot better than I can I think.