# From which interface/class does the Count method come from

Tags: powershell

$HashTable.Values.GetEnumerator().Count | Measure-Object -Sum | Select-Object Sum

in this small peice of powershell code, where is the .Count coming from?

**Where I have searched:**

1. I searched through the documentation for GetEnumerator
   [GetEnumerator Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary.getenumerator?view=net-6.0#system-collections-idictionary-getenumerator)
2. this method returns an object of type IDictionaryEnumerator
   [IDictionaryEnumerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionaryenumerator?view=net-6.0)

and in IdictionaryEnumerator I cannot see any method like GetCount() for which Count can be an aliase.

**summary:** Where is the Count() method defined?

Comment: `Count` is a special synthetic property that PowerShell's Extended Type System evaluates for you at runtime. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26504589/how-does-the-count-property-work-in-powershell

Comment: thank you @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: You're welcome! Does the linked post answer your question? Or are you looking for something else/further?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen No The post answers My question.
You may post your comment as an answer and then I will accept it. =)